# Upload file FTP python passing content as parameter

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I can't access the filesystem of my server (read-only), but I need to upload a "file" via FTP
I have all files information stored in RAM (both file name and file content), is there any way I can upload it on the server without having to `open()` it? As far as I know, `ftplib` can only `STOR` the file if I pass the handler as a parameter.

Comment: you could try to use `file_handler = io.StringIO(data)` to create file-like object with text in memory. Many functions which expect file handler can works with this file-like object. If you have bytes instead of text then you can try `io.BytesIO()`

Comment: @furas `StringIO` does not work with ftplib, at least not out-of-the-box. `BytesIO` does.